# How to find where css files are called from

Tags: css

I am new to css and js. I am really struggling to locate where each individual css file is called from. I have created a combined.css file where i have copied and pasted the code of each css file that loads when my site is loaded, there are 12 files in total. I have added this combined.css into my head section so it loads first. Now the problem is all the other css files are still being loaded. I spending hours looking for are tring different solution, nothing has worked. How do i locate where each individual css file is called from so i can comment this out. If  you can give me a step by step guide i would really appreciate that.

Comment: View the HTML source? Look for `<link rel="stylesheet">` elements. If the HTML source is not readable, you can open the browser's dev tools and check there (Sources panel in Chrome. Network panel would work too).

Comment: Try using something like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).  It will show you all the pieces for each element, as well as what file they are coming from.

Comment: why don't you do a "Find" or "CTRL+F" and just look for the .css file names in the document. Im assuming this isn't your code based off your lack of awareness of where the info is?

Comment: CTRL+F12 Chrome dev tools will give you lots of information of this nature

Answer (score 2):

You can use Chrome (or something similar like Firebug in Firefox).

just hit `F12` on your page to get the `Developers Tool > Resources > Frames > [choose your folder] > Stylesheets` and then you'll get all the CSS that are loaded.

just hover one of them to see its location

[image]

Comment: great guys thanks so much for the info. I am going to try them out. will let you know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: Hi Guys. Ok so i went into my plugins folder and located the $handle using wp-enqueue-style. I then inserted the wp_deregister_style code in my functions.php file like so:                            add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles() {
 wp_deregister_style('wp-pagenavi');
} the wp-pagenavi css file is combined with the other css files in the combined.css file. This code breaks my site however and i get an error pointing to this line (code). Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the help but i seemed to have sorted this out. i had to combine all my codes rather than adding seperate wp_deregister_style codes. So iam sorted. Thanks agin for your help